# Generating functions with power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions

How to find the series expansion for generating function $\frac {1} {1-2x-x^2}$?

I have got so far $$\frac {1} {1-2x-x^2}=-\frac {1} {2\sqrt2} (\frac {1} {1-\sqrt2+x} -\frac {1} {1+\sqrt2+x})$$

$\frac {1} {1-\sqrt2+x}$ is expanded power series of Sum of $(\sqrt2-x)^k$ for $k=0$ to infinity, but how would I express it in terms of $x^k$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you want an expansion as a power series in a neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: i have to find a power series in terms of $a_nx^n$ and then find a recursion relation for an, is that around x=0? sorry im new to Generating functions

Comment: I'm not sure, as this is probably different from questions of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

If you call

$$
P(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x-x^2} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
$$

then:

$$
(1-2x-x^2) P(x) = 1
$$
$$
P(x) = 1 + 2x P(x) + x^2 P(x)
$$

Then we can see that $a_0$ = 1, $a_1 = 2a_0 = 2$, and $a_{n+2} =  2a_{n+1} + a_n$

You can then find the closed form for $a_n$ by finding the roots $r_1, r_2$ of the characteristic polynomial $x^2 - 2x -1 = 0$, namely $r_1 = 1 + \sqrt{2}, r_2 = 1-\sqrt{2}$, and calculating $A,B$ in $a_n = Ar_1^n + Br_2^n$ for the initial conditions
$$
a_0 = A+B = 1
$$
$$a_1 = A(1+\sqrt{2} + B(1-\sqrt{2} = 2
$$
Solving for $A,B$ gives $A=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}, B = \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$, and
$$
a_n = \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4} (1+\sqrt{2})^n + \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}(1-\sqrt{2})^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the expansion near $x=0$, then for $\frac {1} {1-\sqrt2+x}$ you should see it as
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt2-1-x}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt2-1}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(\frac{x}{\sqrt 2-1})}$$
and then use $\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

We may actually find the sequence $(r_n)$ defined by 
$$\frac1{ax^2+bx+c}=\sum_{n\geq0}r_nx^n.$$
We have that 
$$\begin{align}
1&=a\sum_{n\geq0}r_nx^{n+2}+b\sum_{n\geq0}r_nx^{n+1}+c\sum_{n\geq0}r_nx^n\\
1&=cr_0+(cr_1+br_0)x+\sum_{n\geq0}(ar_{n}+br_{n+1}+cr_{n+2})x^{n+2}.
\end{align}$$
Then if we define $cr_0=1$ and $cr_1+br_0=0$ then $r_0=1/c$ and $r_1=-b/c^2$, and 
$$0=\sum_{n\geq0}(ar_{n}+br_{n+1}+cr_{n+2})x^{n+2}.$$
So for any $n\geq0$
$$ar_n+br_{n+1}+cr_{n+2}=0$$
We then have that there exists a solution to the recurrence in the form 
$$r_n=\alpha_1\phi_1^n+\alpha_2\phi_2^n$$
Where $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ are roots of the recurrence's characteristic polynomial, namely
$$cx^2+bx+a=0.$$
So
$$\phi_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2c},\qquad \phi_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2c}.$$
Thus, with $n=0$:
$$r_0=\frac1c=\alpha+\beta$$
and with $n=1$:
$$r_1=-\frac{b}{c^2}=\alpha\phi_1+\beta\phi_2,$$
Which you can use to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

In your case,
$$
a=-1\\
b=-2\\
c=1.
$$
So 
$$r_0=1,\qquad r_1=2$$
and 
$$\phi_1=1+\sqrt2,\qquad \phi_2=1-\sqrt2.$$
So finally 
$$\alpha=\frac{2+\sqrt2}{4},\qquad\beta=\frac{2-\sqrt2}{4}.$$
This gives
$$\frac1{1-2x-x^2}=\frac14\sum_{n\geq0}x^n\left[(2+\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)^n+(2-\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt2)^n\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

Directly:
$$\begin{align}\frac {1} {1-2x-x^2}&=1+(2x+x^2)+(2x+x^2)^2+(2x+x^2)^3+(2x+x^2)^4+\cdots =\\
&=1+2x+(1+4)x^2+(4+8)x^3+(1+12+16)x^4+(6+32+32)x^5+\cdots=\\
&=1+2x+5x^2+12x^3+29x^4+70x^5+\cdots=\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P_kx^{k-1},\end{align}$$
where $P_k=2P_{k-1}+P_{k-2},P_0=0,P_1=1$ is a [Pell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number).